# Problem with inheritance with Lua (attempt to call field 'String' (a nil value))

Tags: inheritance, lua

I am having difficulties with Lua's inheritance.
I am getting an error

> "Error: main.lua:32: attempt to call field 'String' (a nil value)"

What am I misunderstanding ?
I don't understand how my example differs from : https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html

```
Animal = {}

function Animal:New()
    a = {}
    setmetatable(a,Animal)
    a.__index = Animal

    return a
end

function Animal:String()
    print("I am an animal")
end

Cat = {}

function Cat:New()
    c = Animal:New()
    setmetatable(c,Cat) -- Set metatable to be Cat
    c.__index = Animal -- Inherits from Animal

    return c
end

-- Overwriting Bark
function Cat:String()
    print("I am a cat")
end


c = Cat:New() -- Should return a cat
print(c:String())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences between your code and the example in PiL.

1. `Account.new` uses `self`, not `Account` as the metatable for the new object. `self` might refer to `Account` or any subclass.
2. `Account.new` sets the `__index` on `self`, not the new object. This is necessary, because metamethods must go on the metatable, not the object itself, to have any effect.
3. `SpecialAccount` is created with `Account:new()`, not a plain, empty table. Note that that system uses the `new` method to create both subclasses and instances.
4. `SpecialAccount` does not define a `new` method. It simply inherits the one from `Account`.

The error is due to the fact that `c`'s metatable is `Cat`, but `Cat` has no `__index`. `SpecialAccount`'s `__index` is set by its `new` method, when it creates an instance.

Comment: I don’t want to call Animal:New() before I actually need a Cat object thats why Cat is set to {} but I still want a Cat class that inherits from Animal. 

In the lua example SpecialAccount is an object that is initialised with Account:New() whereas I want a Cat class that instanciates Cat.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It sounds like you need a way to separate subclassing from instanciation. Like I said in the answer, `Account:new()` does both jobs. There are lots of ways to do what you want, but the example in PiL isn't one of them. Check out http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming.